# .on or .click function works only once with same name form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form in a php loop, and if there are 3 elements in the database, there are 3 forms with same name. Those forms do contain a button with the same name. So everything likes like this:

```
<form id="test">
  <button id="testbutton"></button>
</form>
<form id="test">
  <button id="testbutton"></button>
</form>
<form id="test">
  <button id="testbutton"></button>
</form>
```

The problem appears when I try to call .on or .click function from javascript. It works only once.

This is the JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#testbutton').on("click", function() {
        function();
    });
});
```

The button fades out certain div's which have different names.

Comment: You never actually asked a question. What do you want help with?

Comment: $('form').on("click", "button ", function(){}

Answer (score 5):

[ID's Must Be Unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme), specifically because it will cause problems in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and CSS when you try to interact with those elements.

Give your elements a class instead :

```
<form>
  <button class="testbutton"></button>
</form>
<form>
  <button class="testbutton"></button>
</form>
<form>
  <button class="testbutton"></button>
</form>
```

Now your selector can use the class:

```
$('form').on("click", ".testbutton", function(){    // event will bubble up to form
```

Comment: I made classes for all. Now, when I click on the 2nd element, the first is deleted and none other work then. Is there something else that is allowing just one .on or .click call?

Comment: What you're asking now is a different question entirely, having to do with the function you're calling on the click. I have changed the `on()` to better reflect event bubbling, so start there.

Comment: I don't want to submit the form, I am using buttons to hide div's. So, the problem is, I can only do it once (all buttons have the same name, like said above).

Comment: Again, what you're asking is another question. What you want to do it give the button an identifier related to the div which should be hidden.

Comment: Okay, I'll try. But why does the click function work only once? I cannot hide 2 div's without refreshing the page.

Comment: The click function, set up with classes, works more than once. The function you have setup to hide the div's is where your problem now lies. Also make sure to remove any non-unique id, like `id="test"` on the forms.

Comment: @SaTTko did you look at the example I posted?

Answer (score 0):

please try to bind event on button type rather than id like this

```
$(':button').on("click", function(){
// do other stuff
});
```

Please check here in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lh82rgj9/)

Comment: While the binding will work, the id's must still be changed.

Comment: ids can be changed with the help of PHP loop variable

Comment: but if ids remain same then still code on the basis of type is running well. Not getting disable

Comment: No it isn't. JavaScript and CSS both have problems when duplicate ID's are used.

Comment: Okay, I have set all buttons a different id. Now, it still works only once when I call the $('button').on("click", function(){

Comment: it is not $('button') it is $(':button') you are missing :

Comment: plz remove all the code from click event for checking purpose and place an alert message. In fiddle I also use preventdefault & stoppagation to stop further event bubbling.
If things work right. Then share your function code which you want to run in this handler. May be there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem with this sentence:

$(this).closest("form").find("input[name=testfield]").val()

It is a bit complicated to explain the problem, but the solution is here. Button click finds the closest form and closest value of the field required. So, my problem is gone, but thanks for all the help, you have helped me to clear out some doubts! :)